# Advice to get selected elements from CheckedTreeSelectionDialog

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I'm using CheckedTreeSelectionDialog to implement some kind of refactoring. The refactoring is performed over a large set of objets, so each root node of the selection tree is a objet, and each of those objects has a suggested modification as a child node. For example,

CheckedTreeSelectionDialog:

```
ObjectA
   ----------  Remove attribute attA1
   ----------  Remove attribute attA2
Object B
   ----------  Remove attribute attB1
.
.
.
```

I obtain the selected elementes this way:

```
Object[] result = dialog.getResult();
```

and, if I select all those 5 elements showed before, I will get the list:

```
ObjectA
attA1
attA2
ObjectB
attB1
```

I thought I would get some kind of tree, for example, where I can get the object "ObjectA" and see which of its childs where selected.

Am I doing this right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively you can get the tree viewer and from that get the checked elements.

```
Map<Object, List<Object>> mapOfCheckedElements = new HashMap<Object, List<Object>>();
    for (TreeItem level1 : checkBoxTreeViewer.getTree().getItems()) {
        if (level1.getChecked()) {
            List<Object> checkedChildren = new ArrayList<Object>();
            for (TreeItem level2 : level1.getItems()) {
                if (level2.getChecked()) {
                    checkedChildren.add(level2);
                }
            }
            mapOfCheckedElements.put(level1, checkedChildren);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, @codejammer , but how can I get the tree viewer from the CheckedTreeSelectionDialog?

Comment: getTreeViewer() method is available on the dialog as per javadoc http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fdialogs%2FCheckedTreeSelectionDialog.html

Comment: I subclasses CheckedTreeSelectionDialog and created a method that does what you suggested, but I get org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed) whet the getItems() is called. any idea?

Comment: You should do this before the dialog is closed.